# Wordpress Installation Time Out

Tags: php, wordpress-theming

I am unable to upload a plugin, it shows an error of max size, I only have the wp-admin. I have been facing this issue many times when trying uploading a plugin. I am a new in wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try by using this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-maximum-execution-time-exceeded/

Comment: Trying to do it

Answer (score 2):

Generally Size limits are configured in php.ini file. If you do not have server access. go to wp-config.php file or index.php file and set upload_max_size to higher memory.

Something like this :

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '10M');
```

Comment: Unable to access those file from wp-admin

Comment: Then you can try editing htaccess thru wpadmin. Here are possible solutions : http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-increase-the-maximum-file-upload-size-in-wordpress/

Comment: I will try this if got access to the files. For me the plugin is best option to do...